# Another word for "bible times"?

Tags: synonyms

Looking for a word or phrase along the lines of "the period of time when the bible was being written".

Example, sentence: "This behavior was prevalent throughout the ??? period."

To clarify, I am looking for a word or phrase that represents the period of time during which (or about which) the events of the bible were recorded. This could be anywhere from 4000BC to 100AD. The expansive period here actually works to my advantage, since I am attempting to illustrate the historical prevelance of said behavior.

The closest I can think of would be "both the old and new testament periods" but sounds clumsy and I was hoping for a shorter alternative.

Comment: The historical issue here is that there were several periods when the Bible was being written. Depending on the part of the Bible we're talking about, we could be looking at 1200 BCE to 100 CE, with a few periods of likely compilation. So the "Biblical period" plays fast and loose. More precise phrases are sometimes jargon (e.g., Iron Age I and II), but Babylonian, Persian, Hellenistic, and Roman periods are easy enough to understand.

Comment: References from both old and new testament are being used in the analysis, and therefore all pre-canonical periods combined is what i'm after (if there is such as thing). I doubt that "pre-canonical" would be the right term, however.

Comment: I've never heard of a word for this.

Comment: The Bible wasn't "written". It is a collection of texts and scriptures: an anthology.

Comment: The term 'patriarchal' is sometimes applied to the Abraham ... Jacob period, but the temporal meaning is only reasonably used in Judaeo-Christian commentaries. But your comment references this period, while the question asks for the period/s when the Scriptures were actually first being  written.

Comment: Could you clarify "the period of time when the bible was being written"? It was compiled in the late fourth century from writings that were probably never intended to be brought together.  This puts the writing of the Bible into a very short period. The alternative is the time of events in the Bible which are referred to as antediluvian, postdiluvian, "at the time of Christ" and "after the crucifixion/resurrection."

Comment: What behavior are you talking about?

Comment: Biblical times, not bible times. With a capital b. No need for a period.

Comment: Okay, I think you just mean *biblical times* now…during which events happened (ark building, boils, etc.), to include the NT, in which one book "cannonized" another (so to speak), its contemporary. Which complicates matters. But I think your wording is rather confusing.

Comment: Yes, with a capital B, "Biblical times" (not *biblical times).

Comment: Also, Old and New Testament, or they'll flunk you. Old and New Testament times.

Comment: Since the only thing that unites these times is the writing of the Bible it's definitely better to call it Biblical Times. Otherwise there are other divisions e.g. First Temple Period (1200 BCE to 586 BCE) and Second Temple Period (586 BCE to 70 CE), or Iron Age (1200 BCE - c. 300 BCE) and what followed (Hellenistic and Roman). Else you can give an explicit time range (700 BCE to 300 CE conservatively). I've seen Classical Israel but I don't think there's an agreed definition (If it matches Greece, Classical probably starts a bit late).

Comment: But this isn't an English language question and should be asked on a Bible/Christianity or history forum?

Answer (score 1):

There really is no specific word for this in English. This seems more a question for the history stack exchange.

However, according to [Wikipedia](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/617414/another-word-for-bible-times) the span from 4000BC to 100AD in the Levant would cover the late Stone Age through to the mid Roman period.

More specifically the Late Chalcolithic period, the whole of the Bronze Age, the whole of the Iron Age, the Hellenistic period and the early Roman period.

Whether something was being written during this time or if there is an accepted term for the meaning you want, are more questions for the history stack exchange.